# Easy way to compute $Pr[\sum_{i=1}^t X_i \geq z]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, summation, convolution

We have a set of $t$ independent random variables $X_i \sim \mathrm{Bin}(n_i, p_i)$.
We know that $$\mathrm{Pr}[X_i \geq z] = \sum_{j=z}^{\infty} { n_i \choose j } p_i^j (1-p_i)^{n_i -j}.$$

But is there an easy way to compute:

$$\mathrm{Pr}\left[\sum_{i=1}^t X_i \geq z\right]?$$

MY IDEAS:
This should have to do something with convolution, but I am not sure.

Is it easier to compute
$$\mathrm{Pr}\left[\sum_{i=1}^t X_i \leq z \right]?$$

What I thought of is maybe:
$$\mathrm{Pr}\left[\sum_{i=1}^t X_i \leq z \right]=\sum_{j=1}^{z} \mathrm{Pr}\left[\sum_{i=1}^t X_i = z \right]$$
but this seems to be quite hard with $t$ random variables.

Would appreciate any hint and if you don't write an answer I am interested in whether it is too difficult or too easy?! thank you..

Comment: partial sum of rows in the Pascal triangle doesn't have a closed form, but you can either 1) use an approximation or 2) use the Central limit theorem. For large $t$ it gives a good approximation.

Comment: I am very interested in an Approximation. How could one approximate this?

Comment: I am mainly intersted in approximations where $n_i p_i \leq 1$ or $n_i p_i \gg 1$, but not for $n_i p_i = O(1)$, if this should be relevant.

Comment: When $t$ is large, approximations with the normal distribution are the way. When $t$ is small, you can rely on the behaviour of the hypergeometric function $\phantom{}_2 F_1$, as shown in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870063/prove-by-induction-that-a-k-sum-limits-n-2k3k-binom3kn-cdot-frac/870480#870480.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLT is indeed applicable here as an approximation to the CDF of a sum of binomial random variables (in particular, the [Lindeberg-Feller CLT](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lindeberg-FellerCentralLimitTheorem.html)) as long as we assume that the $\mathrm{Var}(X_i)=p_i(1-p_1)n_i$ are bounded from above or grow slow enough that individual variances become small compared to the variance of the entire sum (see [Lindeberg Condition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LindebergCondition.html)). This is satisfied as long as the $n_i$ don't drastically increase with $t$.

Given the above assumption (which is usually reasonable), we can use the Lindeberg-Feller CLT to approximate the sum of t binomial random variables:

Let $X_i \sim \mathrm{Bin}(n_i,p_i)$ and $s_t= \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^t n_ip_i(1-p_i)}$. Then the Lindeberg-Feller CLT states that:

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^t (X_i-n_ip_i)}{s_t}\xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}(0,1).$$

Therefore, we can approximate your sum of binomials with a normal distribution:

$\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^t (X_i-n_ip_i)}{s_t}\xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}(0,1)\implies \sum\limits_{i=1}^t (X_i-n_ip_i)\xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0,s_t^2) \implies \sum\limits_{i=1}^t X_i \xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^t n_ip_i,s_t^2\right)$.

Thus, $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow \infty}P\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^t X_i \leq z\right)=\Phi\left(\frac{z-\sum\limits_{i=1}^t n_ip_i}{s_t}\right)$.

Now, the sum of these binomials is really only defined for integer values of z. Therefore, to get an approximation to $P\left(\sum_{i=1}^t X_i \geq z\right)$, just use the above approximation to estimate $1-P\left(\sum_{i=1}^t X_i < z\right)\approx 1-\Phi\left(\frac{z-1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^t n_ip_i}{s_t}\right)$

Comment: is the lindeberg condition true if one can Show that 
$\frac{\sqrt{n_i p_i (1-p_i)}}{s_n}\rightarrow 0$ for every $i$?

Comment: @user136457 yes, if by $\rightarrow$ you mean as $n\rightarrow\infty$ See bottom of page of the link on the Lindeberg condition.

Comment: thanks for your answer. This was really helpful and got an upvote. 
As I am intersted also in an Approximation not in Distribution but as an approximation $1-P[\sum X_i < z] \sim g$ for some $g$, do you know something about this? Could this be possible?

Comment: @user136457 I think there is some confusion on terminology here...what I just gave you was an approximation to $1-P[\sum X_i < z]$. In other words, to use your notation $g = 1-\Phi\left(\frac{z-1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^t n_ip_i}{s_t}\right)$

Comment: @user136457 (clarified) A sum of random variables is a *function*, hence when a sum of random variables converges in distribution, it is the same as saying that it has an approximation.

Comment: Ok, let me state it differently. 
This approximation is in Distribution, isn't it? So, as I am not very good in mathematics, I am not sure whether this gives me some bounds in error. 
What I really would like to know additionally, is whether it is true that the relative error is in $o(1)$ and if one can give a concrete term for the relative error $\frac{1-P[\sum X_i < z]}{g}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15774/discussion-between-eupraxis1981-and-user136457).

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a general idea. If you want the details, look up an article by Tomas Woersch ([here](ftp://ftp.ira.uka.de/pub/uni-karlsruhe/papers/Techreports/1994/1994-31.ps.gz)).

So you have 
$$
S_m(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n}{k}x^k = 1 + \binom{n}{1}x +\ldots + \binom{n}{m}x^m\\
\frac{S_m(n)}{\binom{n}{m}x^m} = 1 + \ldots + \frac{\binom{n}{1}x}{\binom{n}{m}x^m} + \frac{1}{\binom{n}{m}x^m} = 1 + \ldots a_{m-1}x^{1-m} +a_m x^{-m}
$$
Now you need to do the following: obtain the ration of binomial coefficients I denoted with $a_k$ and then approximate then using Stirling approach. Use the fact that 
$$(1 - o(1))\sqrt{2 \pi n} (\frac{n}{e})^n \leq n! \leq (1+o(1))\sqrt{2 \pi n} (\frac{n}{e})^n$$

Comment: So I tried to understand what you mean and also had a look at Woersch's paper. But somehow I miss the link to the original question. 
$S_m(n)=Pr[Bin(n,p)\leq m]$ for $x=p(1-p)^{n/k -1}$
And what you write lets me think that $S_m(n)$ can be approximated by ${ n \choose m} x^m$, thus by the last summand what makes a lot of sense. 
But now, I am intersted in 
$Pr[\sum_i X_i \geq z] = 1- Pr[\sum_i X_i \leq z]$, but then somehow I have to use convolution again?

Comment: Taken together: I think, I understood what you have written, to get an Approximation of $S_m(n)$ but I have no idea how to use $S_m(n)$ to get the probability from above, as I think it has something to do with convolution?

Comment: Here $(\frac{p}{1-p})^n = x$. IF $X_k \sim Binomial (n_k,p)$, then the sum of $m$ variables such that $m n_k = n$ is also Binomial with parameters $n$ and $p$.

Comment: The Problem is that $X_k \sim Bin(n_k, p_k)$ and thus with different probabilities $p_k$. 
Is then something similar possible?
If it helps, we will have $X_k \sim Bin(n_k, \frac{k}{l})$ for some $l$.

Comment: OK< I might have misunderstood your question. Have a look here mb for rvs that are independent but not identically distributed: http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~dhunter/asymp/fall2002/lectures/ln04.pdf

Comment: thanks for your help and this link, but I don't think that this is what I am interested in, as I don't want to get Limits in Distribution.  
Assuming general distributions of the $X_i$. Isn't it possible to find some easier term for this?

Or is it possible to find an Approximation using the mean of all the $p_k$?

Or is it possible to find upper and lower bounds using Minimum value of $p_k$ and Maximum value of $p_k$?